# Jqgrid fade In fade out?

Tags: jqgrid, fadein, fadeout

Does jqgrid supports fade in,fade out, I want to make it fade in fade out when the grid display and reload, is there anyone knows how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to hide it's content or the whole grid?, there is no fade in/out in jqgrid but you can use jquery effect function to create this effect
you can set fadeOut in onBeforeRequest, and fadeIn in loadComplete

```
onBeforeRequest : function(){
  // is used for the whole grid
  $(this).closest('#gbox_'+this.id).fadeOut('slow');

  /*--------- OR ----------*/

  //will fade out only the table inside
  $(this).fadeOut('slow');
},

loadComplete : function(){



  $(this).closest('#gbox_'+this.id).fadeIn('slow');

  /*--------- OR ----------*/

  $(this).fadeIn('slow');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for a visual effect, Liviu's answer is a good one. If you're trying to block user interaction with the grid while it's loading data, what I like to do on my grids is use the BlockUI plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element

My pattern is to block the grid before an ajax call, and then unblock it on the ajax call's success method .

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to inform your users that the grid is loading...(I'm completely assuming this might be at the core of what you are looking for??)...as an alternative to a fadeIn/fadeOut...

I find that the "grid loading" message is not the greatest way to inform users that the grid is loading. For example, if the grid has many rows, the message may not appear in the view area and the user may be looking at old data in the grid (while it's loading) and not realize it...especially if the server processes the ajax slow or the query is slow for whatever reason. Here's a little something I do:

Add this event to your jqgrid setup:

```
beforeRequest: function(){
    $('#grid tr').addClass('gridLoadingClass');
    $('#grid span').css('color','lightgray');
    $('#grid a').css('color','lightgray');
},
```

And add a class like this somewhere in your CSS:

```
.gridLoadingClass {color:lightgray;}
```

Your grid's contents will now "gray out" while loading.